# Physical reason behind $\langle +,x | \hat S_z |+,x \rangle=0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

For a spin half particle we have the following relation:
$$\langle +,x | \hat S_z |+,x \rangle=0$$
I have seen this to derive the Pauli matrices and therefore am wondering without knowing anything about the nature $|+,x \rangle$ what physical reason means that this statement must be true?

Comment: What do you mean by "physical reason"? Also, what do you mean by "I have used this to derive the Pauli matrices"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind By 'physical reason' I mean one that does not rely on the mathematical properties of $\hat S_z$ or $|+,x \rangle$ but on their physical properties (e.g. based on measurements etc.). I meant to say I have seen it used to derive the Pauli matrices - in a ad hoc sort of way, which basically relied on this fact to deduce the form the Pauli matrices.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you have derived a special representation of a group element from a symmetry property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon a rotation, that matrix element is equivalent to
$$
\langle +,z|S_x|+,z\rangle
$$

As $S_x=a S_-+b S_+$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb C$, the matrix element is trivially zero, because $\langle +|-\rangle=0$.

Or put it another way: you can always relabel the axes so that $x\leftrightarrow z$, in which case the matrix element would look like $\langle +|S_x|+\rangle$. This is zero because the diagonal elements of $S_x$ are zero.

The state $|+_x\rangle$ kind of looks like this:
[image]
which means that the spin is mostly in the $x$ direction, but there is a nonzero probability to measure the spin in other directions. Now, by symmetry, the probability to measure $|+_x\rangle$ in the $z$ direction is symmetric w.r.t. the $x$ axis and therefore, on average, $\langle +_x|S_z|+_x\rangle=0$, because there is an equal probability to measure it in the negative $z$ direction and in the positive $z$ direction.

Comment: I would probably count this as a mathematical reason rather then a physical one?!

Comment: what's the difference anyway? :-P [*spin* is not very intuitive, but I'll try to come up with something more intuitive]

Comment: I hope it is more intuitive now. If its not I'll delete the answer.